# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin - Stuck in infinite loop on "double click on this message to install android sdk's"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have been on this for about 2 months before I turned here for assistance. I have VS 2019 and have xamarin installed. When I open a xamarin project, I get 1 warning and 1 error.

The warning:

> Could not find android.jar for API Level 28. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 28 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar missing.)Test.Android

The error:

> The project Test.Android is missing Android SDKs required for building. Double-click on this message and follow the prompts to install them.

Note: In the bottom right corner, by refresh, it does say offline mode.

I have tried every solution I could find on here (and other sites). My android SDK manager is showing up fine, the only one on there, however, is `Android 8.1` - oreo API Level 27. I have verified the auto install sdk's were on, I have ran as administrator, all with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Install latest update for VS2019 and install `Android 9.0 Pie API Level 28` using SDK Manager

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the error. The error is gone but the warning still remains. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to reload VS2019 and rebuild the project

Comment: Now the double click error is back, along with a version conflict error, and the same warning, but it changed to line 26.

Comment: try to set Target framework to another installed version